# Install imagick php module in dreamhost

Tags: php, imagick, dreamhost

I'm tryng to install imagick in my VPS at Dreamhost and when I type "phpize" in the imagick-3.0.1 folder I get this:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
```

I'm following this tutorial: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/ImageMagick_and_imagick_php_module_on_shared_hosting#Configure_PHP_to_use_this_extension

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: VPS should include a certain degree of support from DS. They will probably enable it for you if you just ask them. They do for shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the configure script was looking for the
MagickWand.h file in this directory:

/home/bylifeweb/local/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h

but the file is actually in this directory

/home/bylifeweb/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h

To fix that I simply made a symlink from ImageMagick to ImageMagick-6 and
ran the configure script again, it worked fine that time and I was then
able to run make.

Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/bylifeweb/build/imagick-3.0.1/modules

Comment: Accept your own answer if you found the solution (click the tick under the score!)